# GWT APPCACHE: error

Tags: caching, gwt

I am trying https://github.com/realityforge/gwt-appcache
I see that a appcache file is generated : 
827CA84BADEE9B3DF79226A718305DC5.appcache
But I think it should be called MS.appcache, so is it normal ?
The result is that my applicaction does not work offline, could you help ?

**UPDATE**
MS.gwt.xml

```
<module rename-to='MS'>
```

MS.html

```
<html  manifest="MS.appcache"
```

DispatchServletModule.java (I use GUICE)

```
serve("/MS.appcache").with(ManifestServlet.class);
```

The error in **Chrome Dev Tool console** is:

```
`Application Cache Error event: Manifest fetch failed (404)` [http://3.mananaseguro1.appspot.com/MS.appcache][1]
```

I do not understand, why it is not trying to download the manifest file at this url:
http://3.mananaseguro1.appspot.com/MS/827CA84BADEE9B3DF79226A718305DC5.appcache
Maybe I am not doing a good use of GUICE configuring the mapping/servlet ?

Answer (score 0):

The manifest file 8782AE32DDE65F448A5E40DE0EA5E8C5.appcache is expected, there should probably also be several other *.appcache files generated in the same directory - one per GWT permutation. There is also a permutations.xml file that is used to select the correct manifest . If that is all generating you need to set the manifest attribute in the html and add a manifest servlet as is documented in [1]. If you have done this you should be good to go.

What is the error? What is the manifest it is trying to download? Where have you mapped the servlet to?

[1] https://github.com/realityforge/gwt-appcache/blob/master/README.md

Comment: I have updated the topic, I have always difficulties with servlet, maybe you can understand what is wrong, but I am using guice and not @WebServlet.

Comment: it is trying to download http://3.mananaseguro1.appspot.com/MS.appcache but the file name generated are different for each permutation :  cf. 8782AE32DDE65F448A5E40DE0EA5E8C5.appcache So I do not understand how it could download the good manifest file ?

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like guice is not serving the servlet at /ms.appcache. I can not help you as I have no familiarity with the framework.